# Replacing an ad's frame source

Tags: javascript

I have taken a subdomain from a site but when I'm using it with my site it shows me an ad under the page. I want to get ride of that ad. The page source where the ad's configuration is:

```
<frameset  rows="*,29" >
    <frame src="http://mysubdomaiin.org/Loggedpage.php" name="redir_frame" frameborder=0>

    <frame src="http://mysubdomaiin.org/KHgKKjl_popupgoogle.html" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="ad_frame" 
frameborder="0">
    <noframes>
    Sorry, your browser does not support frames.  Click <a href="http://5.14.121.91:100/Loggedpage.php" TARGET=_top>here</A>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

I've tried to replace it with something using javascript:

```
  function replace(){
  document.getElementsByName('ad_frame').src = "http://www.google.com";
  }
```

but it doesn't work. What should i do?

Comment: How do you know that the site doesn't alter your code after you've submitted it? It is very much possible that it checks if you have deleted the frame's content and restore it every time.

Comment: Maybe.I can find out if you help me with the code.If the code is right that means that you're right.

Comment: Java != JavaScript!!

Comment: It seems very likely that a company whose business model involves your subdomain having an ad shown on it will have some kind of check in place to make sure you aren't just doing this. If you want to show a web site without advertising, you ought to just pay for your own domain, not try to hack some other service.

Comment: I have 6 free domains from "FREENOM" but the problem is that i don't have an static ip and the 80 port is blocked.So i have to use that site with subdomains because they can offer me an port 80 redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not a single element. You'll need to modify the first item of the list:

```
function replace(){
    document.getElementsByName('ad_frame')[0].src = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work!That means that they check the source of the frame every time i load the page?

Comment: @sergiureznicencu What does "not working" mean? Does it give you an error? Does it not change the source? Does it not reload the frame?

Comment: It doesn't replace the source url.It still shows me that anoying ad.

Comment: @sergiureznicencu Where are you calling replace()?

Comment: From the html: <html id="start" onload="replace()">